# Custom checkbox only works with background color, not image

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I wanted to use custom checkboxes on a website so for starters, I worked with a span that I gave a custom background-color and once checked, I changed the background-color in CSS and this worked fine, the background-color changed when the checkbox was clicked on. However, once I replaced the color values by an image background url, it shows the background image in the initial state but it won't change the background-image after the value is checked. The checkbox flashes for a brief time but then continues to have the original background image.

The URL is correct, I can open the image in my browser. I've tried by giving the label rather than the span inside it the background properties but this has the same result. In the inspector in Google Chrome, the new background property is also 'active' (and the old one 'crossed out') so I just can't understand why it continues to show the old one.

The HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="unlimited" name="unlimited" value="unlimited" />
<label for="unlimited"><span></span>Unlimited amount</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
display:inline-block;
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
vertical-align:middle;
background: url("../../static/img/checkbox1.jpg");
cursor:pointer; 
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
background: url("../../static/img/checkbox2.jpg");
}
```

Edit: Fixed typo. Here is the code with just background colors, which works as you'd expect, once clicked the color changes to green, you click again it changes to blue.
CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
display:inline-block;
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
vertical-align:middle;
background: blue;
cursor:pointer; 
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
background: green;
}
```

Comment: Can you also show a piece of code that does work (with the background color rather than the image), so we can compare notes?

Comment: I've added this to the first post just now! Basically it's just the url replaced by a color (for testing), which works fine oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
.input[type="checkbox"] + label span
```

See the full-stop/period in front of `input`?

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-30-30-4.jpg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-30-30-3.jpg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="unlimited" name="unlimited" value="unlimited" />
<label for="unlimited"><span></span>Unlimited amount</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text in your question sounds like you're accidentally double clicking. But a checkbox doesn't have a double click event, so you're simply clicking twice, unselecting the checkbox the second time.

However, the *code* in your question shows an error in the CSS for the unchecked one, namely a extraneous dot in front of the `input`. If I remove that, it works normally.

(Note that I needed to replace the images by something generic.)

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/30/FF0/000.png&text=%20");
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/30/FF0/000.png&text=✔");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="unlimited" name="unlimited" value="unlimited" />
<label for="unlimited"><span></span>Unlimited amount</label>
```

Comment: Ahh, the point happened because I removed some of the classes that were before it to make it more clear to post here (as they were project-specific classes), excuse me. In the code the name is actually correct. I think you might be right about the double click though, sometimes the span next to it gets "selected" when I click the checkbox. I still don't understand why it does work with background colors (it just changes the one time to a different color if I click it) but not with images..

Comment: Hmmmm... slow loading image, so you don't notice immediately that the click did anything, and you click again automatically?

Comment: No, I definitely only click once and then wait a decent amount of time, but still no changing image.. There is (on purpose) another field that gets disabled if this checkbox is checked and that way I definitely know I only clicked once, only if I click again that field gets enabled again. But because it sometimes (not always) selects the labeltext next to it, it feels random to me, I thought you might had a point about some sort of double click event..

Comment: But you still have the problem, only on your site or also in the snippets in the answers here?